# STM32L1 snprintf usage to convert float to string

Tags: floating-point, type-conversion, stm32

I have problem with convert float to str on STM32,
I have two simple functions to print Int and Float
Int work fine, but float print cause program crash

```
void LCD_PrintInt(int value) {
    char str[8];
    sprintf(str, "%d", value);
    LCD_Print(str);
}

void LCD_PrintFloat(float value, uint8_t length) {
    char str[length];
    snprintf(str, length + 1, "%f", value);
    LCD_Print(str);
}

LCD_PrintFloat(99.9, 4); <- crash
LCD_Print("99.9"); <- works fine
```

I'm using STM32CubeIDE and set -u _printf_float linker flag
what am I doing wrong? is float operations (on STM32) is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

For "%d" you need at least 12 characters, you allow only 8.

In the "%f" case, you need 10, but you allocated only 4, and then you told snprintf that you had allocated 5.

The reason you need 10 is for "99.900000" plus one for the null terminator (printf uses 6 decimal places by default).  If you only want one decimal place, then you need to use "%.1f".

No matter how many places you want, you have to tell the function how many bytes are really available.  When you add one for the null terminator you have to add it to the size of the buffer as well, not just the function argument.

[Edit]
I missed the bigger problem is that `%f` requires an argument of type double but you are passing a float.  If you turned warnings on with `-Wall` it would tell you this.

Comment: `void LCD_PrintFloat(float value) {
 char str[10];
 snprintf(str, 10, "%f", value);
 LCD_Print(str);
}`
I allocate 10 or 11 but still program crash

Comment: Which compiler and settings?

Comment: gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32L151xBA -DDEBUG -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L1xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage --specs=nano.specs -mfloat-abi=soft -mthumb

Comment: In C, `float` arguments to a `...`  function are promoted to `double`.  `-Wall` is a good idea, but does not make a difference here.  But maybe STM32 is not C compliant.

Comment: STM32 is the hardware.  It can't be compliant or non-compliant.  I suspect (although he hasn't said) that the OP is using newlib C library which is more-or-less compliant.

Comment: If you called LCD_PrintFloat(99.9, 11); and it still crashed then the problem must be in LCD_Print.  Does it retain a copy of the pointer?  Can you add the source of LCD_Print to the question?

Answer (score 0):

> what am I doing wrong?

Off by 1

Do not tell `snprintf()` there is more room than actually available.  That leads to *undefined behavior* (UB) as OP experienced.

```
char str[length];
// snprintf(str, length + 1, "%f", value);  // One too many
snprintf(str, length, "%f", value);
```

Better to use a format and buffer size suitable for all `float`.   I recommend an exponential format like: `%a`, `%g` or `%e`.
`"%e"` example:

```
//                     -   d   .  dddddddd  e   -  E...E \0
#define FLT_TEXT_SIZE (1 + 1 + 1 +    8   + 1 + 1 + 5   + 1)
char str[FLT_TEXT_SIZE];
snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%.*e", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, value);
```

I suspect OP's `snprintf()` is not well handling cases when the buffer is too small.  Use an *ample* buffer.

Comment: `#include <float.h>
void LCD_PrintFloat(float value) {
 char str[FLT_TEXT_SIZE];
 snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%.*e", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, value);
 LCD_Print(str);
}`
still cause program crash

Comment: @dmvs I suspect either the `snprintf()` itself or its use with FP leads to the issues, perhaps a math library is not liked in.  Good luck

Comment: Should I use another way to convert float to str? To use my LCD_print()

Comment: @dmvs Are you linking in the math library?

Comment: Linker command `gcc -lm`
I'm sorry if I don't understand, but i'm new in STM32

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: use https://github.com/bofh453/ftoa-fast/ to convert float to string

Using newlib, snprintf() supports printing float. sniprintf does not support printing float, only ints.

Let's compare flash used. snprintf uses 20 kbyte more flash than sniprintf(). The ftoa() mentioned above uses 1.5 kbyte flash. Still a lot but a huge improvement over the 20 kbyte bloat of snprintf().

What I suggest is converting float to string using ftoa(), and printing the string using sniprintf().

There is another advantage: snprintf() uses double; ftoa() uses float(). Especially on small mcu's the speed difference is noticeable.

HTH.